# Square root of irrationals

Tags: systems-of-equations, radicals, irrational-numbers

The Art of Problem Solving: Volume 1 by Sandor Lehoczky and Richard Rusczyk - Example 6-14

We are trying to solve the system $xy = -12$ and $x^2 + 2y^2 = 34$, which will eventually help us solve for the square root of an irrational expression.
Solving for $y$ in terms of $x$ in the first equation gets us $y = -12/x$, and substituting that into the second equation gets us $x^4 - 34x^2 + 288$
Factoring the equation $x^4 - 34x^2 + 288=0$ will get $(x^2-16)(x^2-18) = 0$. This leads to two integer solutions, $4$ and $-4$, and two irrational solutions $3\sqrt 2$ and $-3\sqrt 2$.

The authors of the book only use the integer solutions. Why can't we use the irrational solutions?

Edit to clarify: They are using the integer solutions to rewrite the expression $\sqrt{34-24\sqrt 2}$ in the form $x + y\sqrt 2$.

Comment: "Use only the integer solutions" to do what? You say "which will eventually help us solve for the square root of an irrational expression".  Is that what they are used for?  Which irrational expression?

Comment: What are they using those integer solutions _for_?

Comment: Are the authors of the book solving the first system looking only for integers $x,y$ ?

Comment: When we write the expression in the form $x+y\sqrt 2$ we wish to restrict $x,y$ to rational numbers. Otherwise there are infinitely many solutions to $x + y\sqrt 2 = \sqrt{34-24\sqrt2}$ and most of them are not useful.

Answer (score 1):

As you note, the author wants to find *integers* $x$ and $y$ such that
$$x+y\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{34-24\sqrt{2}},$$
so you are looking for integer solutions only. Do note that for $x=\pm3\sqrt{2}$ you get $y=\mp2\sqrt{2}$ and so
$$x+y\sqrt{2}=\pm(3\sqrt{2}-2\sqrt{2}^2)=\mp(4-3\sqrt{2}),$$
which is again the same solution as for $x=\pm4$ and $y=\mp3$.